# Gorm Join table query

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

I currently have a Club and Tag table and I wanted to obtain all of the clubs that have at least 1 of those given tags.

```
type Club struct {
    ID      uint
    Sets    []Tag `gorm:"many2many:club_tag;foreignKey:id;References:name"
}
```

```
type Tag struct {
    ID   uint
    Name string
}
```

I made this query which ends up returning the clubs that have that particular tag most of the time however, sometimes I encounter these issues.

```
var clubs []Club
var tags  []string

db.Joins("JOIN club_tag ON club_tag.club_id=club.id).
   Joins("JOIN tag ON club_tag.tag_name=tag.name").
   Where("tag.name IN ?", tags).
   Find(&clubs)

> ERROR: column club_tag.deleted_at does not exist (SQLSTATE 42703)
> Error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "club_tag" (SQLSTATE 42P01)
```

Am I missing something in this query such that it won't return an error?

I'm currently using GORM v2 and tried to follow this [example](http://v2.gorm.io/docs/query.html#Joins)

Any help is appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply, but this would be help full for anybody searching for a similar kind of issue.

@ttrasn is correct i guess.

I think you used gorm.Model into your struct.

GORM library that embeds some common fields to be used with a database model. These fields are:

```
ID: an auto-incrementing integer primary key
CreatedAt: a timestamp of when the record was created
UpdatedAt: a timestamp of when the record was last updated
DeletedAt: a soft delete timestamp used to mark the record as deleted instead of actually deleting it from the database.
```

By embedding gorm.Model in your own Go struct, you get access to these fields without having to define them yourself, making it easier to work with the database.

if you use

```
db.Where("key_key = ?", sKeyValue).Find(&KeyVal),
```

then gorm will search for the field deleted_at field in your reference table and that creates the cause you looking for.

But, if your object do not want these fields for the search, you can simply ignore these fields by

```
db.Unscoped().
Ex:
db.Unscoped().Where("key_key = ?", sKeyValue).Find(&KeyVal)
```

or else you can use db.Raw() sql
Ex:

```
db.Raw("select * from master.sup_v_keyvalues where key_key= ?", sKeyValue).Scan(&KeyVal)
```

Also note:
If you try to access a DB view which dose not contain the above fields, then simply remove the gorm.Model from the view struct.

Answer (score 0):

based on your errors :

> ERROR: column club_tag.deleted_at does not exist (SQLSTATE 42703)
>
> Error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "club_tag" (SQLSTATE 42P01)

Your first error says you `club_tag` hasn't `deleted_at`, I think your struct has `gorm.Model` data. from documentation of gorm v2:

> GORM defined a gorm.Model struct, which includes fields `ID`, `CreatedAt`, `UpdatedAt`, `DeletedAt`

when you create query for struct which has gorm.Model. gorm in default created `deleated_at = null` on query. so I think you should remove gorm.Model and create what fields you want.

Your second error says your query hasn't any table on join. so I think you must check your table names.